# Zero-counts in Kneser-Ney smoothing

Tags: natural-language, smoothing, interpolation

Hope to get help from someone experienced with implementation of language models. I am trying to implement n-gram model based on Kneser-Ney smoothing, however met the next issue:

Here is simplified equation for 4-gram Knesey-Ney smoothing computation.

[image]

The main purpose of smoothing and interpolation here is to involve into calculation of word's probability the lower levels of given ngram. The next part of equation:

[image: Weight for lower ngram]

represents the weight for lower ngram in equation, however with high n-grams as trigrams or higher, the sequence of words in test data quite possible will not occur even once in train data. That will make the weight equal to zero and since, all calculations with lower n-grams don't have a sanse. Moreover, it will return a zero probability, even all words in a given ngram are presented in vocabulary.

So, my question is if I understand correctly the model and Kneser-Ney smoothing and how it's possible to manage with zero-counts of particular words' sequences in this case.

Thanks you so much!

Comment: please fix your title

Comment: done, any suggestions?

Comment: Not really my area, sorry

Comment: What do you mean that all calculations with lower n-grams don't have a sense? Using the lower order n-grams is exactly how the smoothing is done.

Comment: as I ve understood, the equation in Kneser Ney smoothing should be solved recursively from the very low level of n-gram to the highest one. The probabilities of lower ngram then multiplied on lambda weight, which in fact with high-order ngrams as 4-gram will be equal to zero in case the exact SEQUANCE of words was unseen in traininng data. So finally, we will multiply weighted probabilities of lower ngrams on zero.

Comment: That's why calculations with lower n-grams dont have a sence in such a case. And exactly this point is unclear for me, because even for trigram such a case  quite probably will occur. OR I dont understand how the smoothing should be calculated.

Comment: I think you should assume the back-off weight is equal to one instead of zero for these cases.